# In PHP, how can I convert a float probability between 0 and 1, inclusive, into an array index?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am looking for a way to convert a floating point value between 0 and 1, inclusive, into an array index.

The idea is to randomly pick an array element based on a float probability value. I came up with the below code, which attempts to do this a 1000 times. And then tracks how often each value was selcted in the $counts array.

The get_rand_index_1() function uses round(), with $count - 1. The problem here is that the first and last indexes, in this case 0/Apples and 5/Pineapples, only get selected half as often. Leading to $counts being something like:

```
Array
(
    [Apples] => 142
    [Oranges] => 236
    [Bananas] => 269
    [Pineapples] => 104
    [Pears] => 249
)
```

I also wrote get_rand_index_2(). This uses floor() instead of round(), and $count instead of ($count - 1). This I think does the job, but there is an issue if the float is 1. In that case the index will be invalid. Of course this is extremely unlikely, but still theoretically possible. And might be an issue if generating millions of random values at a time.

So I did subtracted 1 / mt_getrandmax(). And then just in the rare case that turns the number negative, I used max(0, ...).

I think this get_rand_index_2() works, the resulting $counts array seems to have evently distributed values. But it seems a little hacky. Also I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way.

Is there a more elegant, or efficient, way to do what I want?

Here is the code I am testing with.

```
<?php

$array = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Pears", "Pineapples"];
$count = count($array);
$counts = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    //$index = get_rand_index_1($count);
    $index = get_rand_index_2($count);
    $value = $array[$index];
    if (!isset($counts[$value])) $counts[$value] = 1;
    else $counts[$value]++;
}
print_r($counts);

function get_rand_index_1(int $count)
{
    $float_rand = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
    $index = round($float_rand * ($count - 1));
    return $index;
}

function get_rand_index_2(int $count)
{
    $float_rand = max(0, mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() - 1 / mt_getrandmax());
    $index = floor($float_rand * $count);
    return $index;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `mt_rand(0, $count - 1)`?

Comment: See my recent answer to this question which is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700581/will-converting-hash-to-integer-using-modulus-result-in-an-even-uniform-distri/77703983#77703983

Comment: @Olivier I think the question is about how to convert [0,1] into [0,N], it is not about how to use mt_rand.

Comment: @shingo In that case, the function should also take the float as a parameter, not just `$count`.

Comment: @Tristan Why not use `random_int(0, $count - 1)`?

Comment: @lukas.j Because he doesn't need a cryptographically secure RNG.

Comment: @shingo Yes thanks that’s correct, this is actually part of a broader script where I want to convert a string to a sha1() hash, then convert that to a float. And then convert that to an array index. I felt like it would confuse things if I specified all that, but I guess the question can seem odd without the context, since Olivier is right that the index could just be randomly picked directly :)

Comment: @Olivier I would always chose `random_int` over `mt_rand`. A reason often underestimated is that `mt_rand` always returns an int, even if it fails to generate a valid value, while `random_int` throws an exception.

Comment: @lukas.j Why would it "fail to generate a valid value"?

Comment: @Olivier Any non-pure function can fail, and generating random numbers is inherently non-pure. There was also an attempt to deprecate (and possibly remove in PHP 9) all Mersenne-Twister-based functions, see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_8_3. It didn't get enough votes, but it lists the problems of these functions.

Comment: *"I want to convert a string to a sha1() hash, then convert that to a float"* Why do you need to convert the hash to a float? How about telling us your real goal behind all this?

Comment: @Tristan you'd better ask that, because it's possible to generate a random value in the range [0,1): `mt_rand() / (mt_getrandmax() + 1.0)`, this is how `mt_rand(min, max)` works.

Comment: @Olivier Well to try and be brief, I’m trying to convert strings to hashes, and hashes to probabilities. So that I can make random numbers that are associated with strings. Thus a string acts as a consistent seed for a random probability. Thus if I had an array of N elements, “Hello world” and “Apple” would both be associated with random, but different and consistent, array indexes. I can convert the string to a float, but I had the issue I mentioned in the question, with when the float was 1.0. I wasn’t sure what the best/fastest way to deal with that was. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @shingo Great thanks for the float [0, 1) suggestion :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below function to evenly distribute random index selection by scaling the random `float` to the array length, using floor for rounding, and ensuring the index stays within bounds.

```
function get_rand_index(int $count) {
    $float_rand = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
    $index = floor($float_rand * $count);
    $index = min($index, $count - 1);
    return $index;
}
```

Comment: And how is this better than `mt_rand(0, $count - 1)`?

Comment: @Olivier The function get_rand_index(int $count) is potentially better than mt_rand(0, $count - 1), By dividing mt_rand() by mt_getrandmax(), you normalize the random number to a float between 0 and 1. Multiplying this float by $count and then using floor ensures a more uniform distribution across the entire range of indices.
The use of min($index, $count - 1) effectively handles the edge case where the calculated index might equal $count (which is out of bounds). This is a more robust approach than directly using mt_rand(0, $count - 1), which might not handle such edge cases as gracefully.

Comment: So you're claiming that `mt_rand()` is biased and that your function provides a better distribution? Proof?

Comment: This will be subject to [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) unless `mt_getrandmax()+1` is an integer multiple of `$count`.